# javascript date display

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HCqsM/5/

Here By clicking the 'click' link for the first text field, the date picker displayed. By selecting the date, it will be populated on text field. Then click the first text field , (the date + 7days) will be populated in the next text field.

I want to populate this while i selected the date from date picker.

i.e by selecting the date for the first text field, the date+7 days will be automatically populated in to the next field. How to achieve this.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you have a lot of "open" questions, are you sure you didn't get an answer for all of them (**48**)?

Comment: My only question is how to write the click event for the chosen date. Then only i can populate the date for the next field.

Comment: What gdoron is saying is that you will get better help if you accept some answers from this list: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1101208/designersvsoft?tab=questions where the answer is useful to you.   If not, go back to those and clarity so you DO get an answer you like - then click the check mark by the answer you find fills the request of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My tip is to add an EventListener to either the field frdt1 (onChange) or to all of the date selectors in calendar 1 (onClick). This listener should then execute a function defined by you which sets the value of frdt2 accordingly. This is not hard because JS date functions recognize a large number of date formats.

[Optional] You should also get/set a global variable in the event listener function such that it will not modify the frdt2 once the user has set this one manually. This will require event listeners on all selectors in calendar 2 (onClick).

more about event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

more about Javascript Date functionality: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp